# How to parse an array of a json Object?

Tags: javascript, json

I want to parse json data so I wrote this program:

```
function(result){
      var tr;
      var str = JSON.stringify(result);
      obj = JSON.parse(str);
      console.log("length " + obj.value[0].length);
      console.log("obj : " + obj);
      }
```

I got a result such:

```
length undefined 

obj: Object { value : Array[7] }
```

How can I loop the array to extract data contained in it?

Comment: so why are you stringifying then parsing it again? Also post what the JSON looks like (abbreviated if necessary)

Comment: Use directly: `obj.value.length`

Comment: Can you give an example of what the JSON looks like? You're running `.length` on an object; an object has no length, you need to target a specific property of that  object. **EDIT:** My mistake, misinterpreted code when skimming over.

Comment: @MatthewW, no,`obj.value` is an `array`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Some observations :**

- What is the purpose of doing `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse` ?
- `length undefined` means that `obj.value[0]` is not available.
- Instead of doing `obj.value[0].length` use this `obj.value.length`

**DEMO**

```js
var obj = { value : [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] };

console.log("length ", obj.value.length);
console.log("obj : ", obj);
```